# IE9 Empty Text Node For All Elements

Tags: html, css, debugging, internet-explorer-9

I've been racking my brain over this for the past few days and haven't been able to find a fix yet. I'm working on a website for a client and it displays fine in Chrome and FF, but IE9 renders it unusable. The navigation bar (everything to the right of the logo) is pushed down. If I open IE's developer tools, every element receives an "Text - Empty Text Node" message and some of my HTML elements appear to be duplicated with no content inside of them.

- WEBSITE REMOVED - PROBLEM SOLVED.

I'm at a loss on this one, as I've tried several fixes including removing white-space. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: first step, validate the markup http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dannyspizzaflorida.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Oh my god, what a stupid mistake. Sometimes you need that kick in the ass. Never closed off an </a> tag.

Comment: Some browsers are more forgiving than others with invalid HTML. When the result is completely chaotic and differs from browser-to-browser, that often points to bad HTML. A similar problem happens in IE8 and earlier when HTML5 tags are used (header, footer, section) without an html5shiv.